# dead.mailer php sinology nas

Tags: php, email, send

I'm trying to make a registration form where at the end a mail is sent to the person who has just registered, to confirm the mail. I've loaded everything on my Sinology nas(RS10613xs+) but when the php script arrives at the point where it must send the mail this error comes out: Warning: mail(vlume1/web/LOG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /volume1/web/email.php on line 13 Mailer
and creates a file called dead.mailer does anyone know how to solve and fix this problem
(I'm still "beginners" with php)

Comment: Please show your PHP code

Comment: The warning tells you that the path `/volume1/web/vlume1/web/LOG` is non-existing. I think you want `./LOG` instead of `vlume1/web/LOG` (typo?). But share your code so we can help.

Comment: I solved the file path problem. Here's the real mistake:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /volume1/web/email.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /volume1/web/email.php on line 3

Comment: I don know what i need to add and ho